# How to make nodes the same height

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I want to make the outer boxes in the diagram below the same height:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit, calc}

\definecolor{craneColor}{RGB}{105,97,140}
\definecolor{sysColor}{RGB}{115,174,66}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
    craneComponent/.style={rectangle, draw=black!50, font=\scriptsize\ttfamily, anchor=west, fill=craneColor, text=white, minimum width=3cm },
    systemComponent/.style={rectangle, draw=black!50, font=\scriptsize\ttfamily, anchor=north west, fill=sysColor, text=white, minimum width=3cm},
    %domainBox/.style={rectangle, minimum height=7.5cm, align=center},
    domainBox/.style={rectangle},
    title/.style={font=\sffamily, anchor=north west}
]

\node [title] (adminDom) at (0,0) {Administrative Domain};

% dom0 contents
\node [ craneComponent, below = of adminDom ] (hostDaemon) {Host Migration Daemon};
\node [ domainBox, draw=black!50, fit={ (adminDom) (hostDaemon) }] (bigAdminBox) {};

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\node[title, right = of adminDom] (guestDom) {Guest Domain};

% domU contents
% user
\node [ craneComponent, below = of guestDom ] (guestDaemon) {Guest Migration Daemon};
\node [ craneComponent, right = of guestDaemon ] (ourLib) {Interposition Library};
\node [ systemComponent, above = of ourLib ] (app) {OpenCL Application};
\node [ systemComponent, below = of ourLib ] (sysLib) {OpenCL Library};
% kernel
\node[ systemComponent, below = of sysLib] (GpuDriver) {GPU Driver};
\node[ systemComponent, below = of GpuDriver] (Gpu) {GPU};

\node [ domainBox, draw=black!50, fit={ (guestDom) (guestDaemon) (ourLib) (app) (sysLib) (GpuDriver) (Gpu) }] (bigGuestBox) {};

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\node[title, right = of guestDom] (proxyDom) {Proxy Domain};
%\node[title, right = of bigGuestBox] (proxyDom) {Proxy Domain};
\node [title] (proxyDom) at (12, 0) {Proxy Domain};

% proxy contents
% user
\node[ craneComponent, below = of proxyDom] (proxyProcess) {Proxy Process};
\node[ craneComponent, below = of proxyProcess] (rpcStub) {RPC Stub};
\node[ systemComponent, below = of rpcStub] (proxySysLib) {OpenCL Library};
% kernel
\node[ systemComponent, below = of proxySysLib] (proxyGpuDriver) {GPU Driver};
\node[ systemComponent, below = of proxyGpuDriver] (proxyGpu) {GPU};


%\node [ domainBox, right of =right of = bigGuestBox,  bigGuestBox, draw=black!50, fit={ (proxyDom) (proxyProcess) (rpcStub) (proxySysLib) (proxyGpuDriver) (proxyGpu) }] {};
\node [ domainBox, draw=black!50, fit={ (proxyDom) (proxyProcess) (rpcStub) (proxySysLib) (proxyGpuDriver) (proxyGpu) }] {};

% edges:
\draw[->] (hostDaemon) -- (guestDaemon);
\draw[->] (guestDaemon) -- (ourLib);
\draw[->] (ourLib) -- (sysLib);
\draw[->] (app) -- (ourLib);
\draw[->] (ourLib) -- (rpcStub);
\draw[->] (rpcStub) -- (proxySysLib);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried setting domainBox class's property of `minimum height`. Here is what I got:
[image]

The outer boxes are now the same height but the alignment is off. Do you know why?

Comment: Could you make a complete example with necessary packages, libraries and colour definitions?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add one more coordinate for the `fit` node in the first and second case. For example,

```
\node [ domainBox, draw=black!50, fit={ (adminDom) (hostDaemon) (adminDom.south|-proxyGpu.south) }] (bigAdminBox) {};
```

Here I added `(adminDom.south|-proxyGpu.south)`, which is the coordinate that has the x-coordinate of `adminDom.south`, and the y-coordinate of `proxyGpu.south`.

Of course, the `proxyGpu` node has to be available, so I moved the two first `fit` nodes to near the end of the code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}%{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\definecolor{craneColor}{RGB}{105,97,140}
\definecolor{sysColor}{RGB}{115,174,66}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
    craneComponent/.style={rectangle, draw=black!50, font=\scriptsize\ttfamily, anchor=west, fill=craneColor, text=white, minimum width=3cm },
    systemComponent/.style={rectangle, draw=black!50, font=\scriptsize\ttfamily, anchor=north west, fill=sysColor, text=white, minimum width=3cm},
    %domainBox/.style={rectangle, minimum height=7.5cm, align=center},
    domainBox/.style={rectangle},
    title/.style={font=\sffamily, anchor=north west}
]

\node [title] (adminDom) at (0,0) {Administrative Domain};

% dom0 contents
\node [ craneComponent, below = of adminDom ] (hostDaemon) {Host Migration Daemon};

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\node[title, right = of adminDom] (guestDom) {Guest Domain};

% domU contents
% user
\node [ craneComponent, below = of guestDom ] (guestDaemon) {Guest Migration Daemon};
\node [ craneComponent, right = of guestDaemon ] (ourLib) {Interposition Library};
\node [ systemComponent, above = of ourLib ] (app) {OpenCL Application};
\node [ systemComponent, below = of ourLib ] (sysLib) {OpenCL Library};
% kernel
\node[ systemComponent, below = of sysLib] (GpuDriver) {GPU Driver};
\node[ systemComponent, below = of GpuDriver] (Gpu) {GPU};


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\node[title, right = of guestDom] (proxyDom) {Proxy Domain};
%\node[title, right = of bigGuestBox] (proxyDom) {Proxy Domain};
\node [title] (proxyDom) at (12, 0) {Proxy Domain};

% proxy contents
% user
\node[ craneComponent, below = of proxyDom] (proxyProcess) {Proxy Process};
\node[ craneComponent, below = of proxyProcess] (rpcStub) {RPC Stub};
\node[ systemComponent, below = of rpcStub] (proxySysLib) {OpenCL Library};
% kernel
\node[ systemComponent, below = of proxySysLib] (proxyGpuDriver) {GPU Driver};
\node[ systemComponent, below = of proxyGpuDriver] (proxyGpu) {GPU};


%\node [ domainBox, right of =right of = bigGuestBox,  bigGuestBox, draw=black!50, fit={ (proxyDom) (proxyProcess) (rpcStub) (proxySysLib) (proxyGpuDriver) (proxyGpu) }] {};


% boxes
\node [ domainBox, draw=black!50, fit={ (adminDom) (hostDaemon) (adminDom.south|-proxyGpu.south) }] (bigAdminBox) {};
\node [ domainBox, draw=black!50, fit={ (guestDom) (guestDaemon) (ourLib) (app) (sysLib) (GpuDriver) (Gpu) (guestDom.south|-proxyGpu.south) }] (bigGuestBox) {};

\node [ domainBox, draw=black!50, fit={ (proxyDom) (proxyProcess) (rpcStub) (proxySysLib) (proxyGpuDriver) (proxyGpu) }] {};

% edges:
\draw[->] (hostDaemon) -- (guestDaemon);
\draw[->] (guestDaemon) -- (ourLib);
\draw[->] (ourLib) -- (sysLib);
\draw[->] (app) -- (ourLib);
\draw[->] (ourLib) -- (rpcStub);
\draw[->] (rpcStub) -- (proxySysLib);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```